# ARM development quickstart

Tags: arm, bare-metal

I want to try developing with ARM platform, particularly I'm interested in bare metal. I'm trying to start that using QEMU but this way of learning lacks comprehensive tutorials and it inevitably adds another level of complexity. Please, suggest a decent ARM development platform that meets the following requirements (sorted by descending importance):

1. Accompanied with a good step-by-step tutorial.
2. Provides basic input/output. I want to see some blinking and be able
   to press some buttons on it. Additionally, having a digit display
   (like on a calculator) or even an lcd display would be wonderful
3. Provides at least some debugging capabilities.
4. Modern.

Comment: http://github.com/dwelch67  in the yagbat repo I have a qemu example, I need to make some standalone qemu examples.

Comment: the stmf0 and f4 discovery are about half to a 10th of the price of th mbed (and have more power) the stellaris launchpad is also an f4 under $20 as well.  I have bare metal examples for a lot of boards.

Comment: you can also use the raspberry pi. Unbrickable. faster than others in that price range (well under the mbed), documentation is not that great, but good support from other users in the raspberry pi bare metal forum.  I agree with Santhosh the mbed will have a better totorial type experience, by the same token there are arm based arduinos that strive to give the arduino experience (teensy 3.0, maple, etc).  I would start down the avr path first though if you need that enviroment.

Comment: technically the mbed and arduino sandbox experience is bare metal, they have put a layer between you and the hardware that it is no more than writing an application on an operating system.  You dont really get to find out how things work, someone else takes that away from you.  (you can use that hardware without the associated sanboxes).

Comment: This is one of those perfectly fine questions that were closed for ridiculous reasons. This question should be reopened.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to start of with ARM controllers , you can go for mbed.mbed boards come with LPC
 1768 32-bit Arm controller. You need not know much about the underlying hardware to code as       there are many builtin api's to work with GPIO's and to interface sensors.

You can follow the mentioned link for the same [mbed](http://mbed.org/)